# Lync Server 2013 Enable-CSComputer throws Error 'Index was out of range'

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, lync, lync-2013

I am trying to install Lync Server 2013 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 but during the server component installation I get the Error

> Error: Command execution failed: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

The error happens on this step (report path truncated):

> This step will configure services, apply permissions, create firewall
>   rules, etc. Executing PowerShell command: Enable-CSComputer
>   -Confirm:$false -Verbose -Report "....html"

Image with complete report (cannot embedded image due to lack of reputation):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1XfG.png

I have reinstalled all the components already but the error persists.

The Server is also hosting a Team Foundation Server 2012. To prepare for Lync I removed the TFS WebSite Binding for Port 8080 disabled it in IIS.

What causes the error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the installer. Please consider contacting Microsoft support.

Comment: Any other Microsoft product installed on your server (except Windows), like Sharepoint, DC etc...?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. There is a TFS 2012 Server installed. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

As it file while doing the "Enable new Roles" I assume it didn´t like you Team Foundation Server running on the same OS. I would fully remove that or better start with a brand new OS.